No approval process found error even though skip entry criteria selected
We have an existing process builder which triggers the approval process . The process is set to ignore entry criteria but it gives error "Approval process not found " for only one user .
I reviewed object access for that particular user , so they have Read , Create ,Edit permission on the object. The user is not the record owner or creator.
Is there any other check that I am missing.
Thanks

Is the AP active? What about the record onwer? Is he/she active? Are you using record types for this object? Even though the user has acces to the object, he/she may not have access to a particular record type.

@Rodrigo Yes the AP is active , the record owner as well as the other user that tried to submit the approval are active , they have access to the object as well as to the record type too .

does the user have access to the specific record? (not just CRUD or the recordType). Use the Sharing button on the record in question to see if that user has access to that object's record
